# Need to port Fortran code using the DFWIN module to gcc/gfortran, where do I start?

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran

**UPDATE** After some digging I found this to be a part of some workaround that passed a file handle from C++ to Fortran using a stub for `OPENPIPE`. `OPENPIPE` simply returns an externally declared file handle, doing absolutely nothing with a pipe. `OPENHOLDFILENAME` actually creates a file, but I'm still confused about what `DFWIN` has to do with this. Was it required to provide a function declaration for `OPENPIPE`? If so, they why was it also declared as `EXTERNAL` in the Fortran code?

---

I was given the task of compiling legacy Fortran on the GCC toolchain. I've already successfully compiled a few of the source files, but have hit a snag regarding the `DFWIN`  module which links up to some Win32 API functions. It apparently uses some Win32 pipe functions, and I need to replace this with a modern equivalent that works with gfortran (the old compiler was Compaq Visual Fortran).

First, I see the `DFWIN` module included, as well as some external functions:

```
    USE DFWIN
    EXTERNAL OPENPIPE
    EXTERNAL OPENHOLDFILENAME
```

Here is an example of how `OPENPIPE` is used:

```
    OPEN(UNIT=INN,FILE=
    1   '\\.\pipe\input.txt',
    1   FORM='FORMATTED',STATUS='old',readonly,
    1   USEROPEN=OPENPIPE)
```

What module can I use to replace these calls on modern Windows/Linux systems using gcc/gfortran?

**EDIT**: Our priority is to get this running on Windows, but in the future we want to deploy on Linux as well.

Comment: What do the pipes actually do? You may find some external library, bit nothing intrinsic.

Comment: I think just read from an input file, but the comment about the OPEN call has me confused: _"Reading from an anonymous pipe. I realize I'm specifying a file name here; it's required to make the USEROPEN think work (I think)."_

Comment: You mentioned linux systems. Are you switching from Windows to Linux, or staying on Windows platform? Does your program use any of the CVF's QuickWin graphics libraries?

Comment: When you say "What module can I use to replace these calls on modern Windows/Linux systems...?", are you planning on compiling for both Linux and Windows?  Cross-platform compiling is it own special kind of headache especially since MS has thier of doing thing and Unix/Posiz has another.

Comment: Well, I should have clarified. This software used to be Windows only, but we are now building it with Qt in the hopes that we can also deploy on Linux. For the time being I need to get this working on Windows, I'll worry about Linux afterword. Although if a platform neutral solution exists that would be great.

Comment: After finding out more, this seems to be a very localized problem. I still need to find an alternative for DFWIN, but I'll repost when I have a more answerable scenario. I do appreciate the help though!